# Converting a ts (Time Series) object to a Vector in R

Tags: data-structures, r, time-series

I need to use a function on a vector that does not take a ts object. I'm trying to convert it to a plain old vector but I just can't seem to figure it out. I googled around but mostly people are trying to convert data types into ts object. I want to go the other way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
data(AirPassengers)   # already in your R installation, via package "datasets"
AP = AirPassengers    
class(AP)
# returns "ts"

AP1 = as.numeric(AP)
# returns "numeric"

# another way to do it
AP1 = unclass(AP)
```

AP1 is a vector with the *same* ***values*** and length as AP. The class is now numeric instead of ts, which means, in part that the indices are no longer some sort of date-time object but just ordinary sequential integers.

So w/r/t the specific question in the OP, either of the two snippets above will "*convert [a ts object] to a plain old vector*"

If you need to do the same thing with the *indices* rather than, or in addition to, the values--ie, from Date objects to numeric, you can do that like so:

```
fnx = function(num_days_since_origin, origin="1970-01-01") {
  as.Date(num_days_since_origin, origin="1970-01-01")
}

a = as.Date("1985-06-11")
a2 = as.numeric(a)
# returns: 5640
a3 = fnx(5640)
# returns: "1985-06-11" (a date object)
```

Comment: +1 I love unclass. It is a great way to inspect the contents of an object in R.

Comment: Seriously? as.numeric(AirPassengers) returns the sampled value at that date, not the date itself.  Please please demonstrate how to get seconds since epoch from the data instead!